# Upgrading laravel into 8 I got illuminate/support support?

Tags: laravel, laravel-upgrade

I try to upgrade my laravel 8 as I read here
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade

But after I applyid some changes in composer.json I got error :

```
 $ composer update
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
 Problem 1
    - illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires artesaos/seotools ^0.20.2 -> satisfiable by artesaos/seotools[v0.20.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - artesaos/seotools v0.20.2 requires illuminate/support 5.8.* || ^6.0 || ^7.0 || ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev], laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^v9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev].
    Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Now composer.json has :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.1",
        "artesaos/seotools": "^0.20.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^1.0.0",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^9.0.0",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "1.0.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "laravel/framework": "^v9.0",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^2.4.4",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.12.1",
        "laravel/telescope": "^4.6.6",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.6.2",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.7.2",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1.33",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.3.6",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^9.0.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.3.1",
        "te7a-houdini/laravel-trix": "^2.0.5",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.6.4",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.16",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.12.3",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Library/helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi"

        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

and I do not see any illuminate* packages referenced in it...

How that can be fixed ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 9 requires PHP 8.

1. Delete the `^7.3|` in composer.json at the line `PHP`The correct syntax is: `"php": "^8.0"`
2. Delete the `v` in composer.json at the line `laravel/framework`, The correct syntax is: `"laravel/framework": "^9.0",`
3. And check the package's `artesaos/seotools` compatibility with the Laravel 9